# No layout manager attached; Skipping layout

Tags: java, android, mobile-application, mobile-development

**Code :**
rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById (R.id.recyclerview);

```
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false);
    CustomRVAdapter customRVAdapter = new CustomRVAdapter (getApplicationContext (),R.layout.custom_rv_row,new StudentList ().getDefaultStudentList ());
    rv.setAdapter (customRVAdapter);
```

**ERROR**
Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceCounter(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light greylist, reflection)

E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout

I/le.assignment_: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=1577 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the layout manager to the recycler view like so:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false);
rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```